# Network appears to be down when it isn't

Tags: database, networking, vb6, dao, jet

A client is using our app over a LAN.

A VB6 front end accesses a Jet database via DAO.

The database connection is is kept open for the duration.
They are getting errors like as though the network is down when it isn't.

If I can explain:
Sometimes when there's a dodgy network connection a query will fail giving an error along the lines of "unable to find table A". As soon as the network is up again this instance will resume working properly again.

In this case however  what happens is that an instance will go down in the manner described above but if a new instance is started it will behave properly (until after a random period it too hangs) meanwhile the previous instance will keep returning error messages suggestive of a network being down and never resume working properly.

Does anyone have an idea what this could be?

****UPDATE 08 Feb2011 The problem has been resolved ****

The cause of this problem was the the computer storing the database had a static IP while the rest had dynamic IPs. The static IP address fell within the range from which the dynaic ones were selected.
Eventually a dynamic address was generated identical with the static one and caused the issues described above.
Thanks to everyone for their comments

Comment: Too many different things could be happening there. Debugging network problems via questions & answers require a large go-and-back message transit and much more info on your side. I don't think Stack Overflow design is good for this

Comment: OK Thank you. If anyone can point me to any resources on the web that might be relevant I'd be grateful

Comment: There's no point in reading beyond "dodgy network connection" in your question. Fix the network. Because of the way Jet/ACE works, it's extremely susceptible to any problems in the networking environment, and if you're going to use Jet/ACE as your back end, you simply have to have a rock-solid network. FWIW, I have almost never encountered this issue, but I urge my clients to buy decent equipment.

Comment: You might like to look at http://serverfault.com/search?q=dodgy+network+connection

Comment: Thanks everyone, I've edited the question to include the solution that was found by the person looking after the network

Comment: Just to add to this, I recently had to fix a network where they were having not these kinds of problems, but terribly slow performance, and it turned out there were hardwired entries in the HOSTS file on the workstations that pointed to an obsolete IP address for the server. So, there were two IP addresses for the Server, and that was causing everything to get confused. Removing the HOSTS entry fixed the problem.